# a web application having three textbox under one Label "Full Name".

Tags: sql, label, textfield

textbox "First Name","Middle Name","Last Name" under Label "Full Name"

i want to specify Label and textbox......how to query?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

if I do this:
create table FullName(FName,MName,LName)
values (' ',' ',' ')

is this right?

Comment: A web application? In what language? Using what server technology? The database is only one component of a web application. You, at minimum, have to have logic mapping user interface logic to database logic and logic for handling url routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to create your FullName table.

```
CREATE TABLE FullName 
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     FName varchar(20), 
     MName varchar(20), 
     LName varchar(20) 
    );
```

Note: The column "id" was added to uniquely identify each row within your table.  There is always a possibility you would have two or more people with the same name.

Here is code you would use to search for a record.

```
SELECT *
FROM FullName
WHERE Fname='Rob'
AND LName ='Roy'
AND MName='Edward'
```

Comment: Hi @tanuja if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.